# How does Ruby use symbols to reference variable names?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

When we are defining getter and setter methods for `name` in the following code:

```
class Animal
    attr_accessor :name
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end
```

what is happening internally? How is Ruby able to take a symbol and match it with a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) and [`instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) for that.

**Update**: as Andrew Marshall noted, not exactly. Most ruby core methods are defined in C, but the result is essentially the same.

One could define `attr_accessor` and friends as follows:

```
def self.attr_accessor(*names)
  names.each do |name|
    define_method(name) do
      instance_variable_get("@#{name}")
    end

    define_method("#{name}=") do |new_value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{name}", new_value)
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I've also used [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method) here to define the accessor methods.

I recommend that you take a look at some introductory texts about ruby metaprogramming, such as ["Don’t Know Metaprogramming In Ruby?"](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/11/23/dont-know-metaprogramming-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't match it with a variable, `attr_accessor` does essentially this (it's actually written in C, but I've written it's roughly Ruby translation here):

```
def attr_accessor(var_name)
  ivar_name = :"@#{var_name}"
  define_method(var_name) do
    instance_variable_get ivar_name
  end
  define_method("#{var_name}=") do |value|
    instance_variable_set ivar_name, value
  end
end
```

As you can see, it simply uses the symbol passed to create two methods. It doesn't do anything fancy with the symbol, and is mostly just passing it through. Note, also, that all instance variables "exist" by default and are set to `nil`, so this will never blow up.